# Parsing (psuedo-)XML with undefined namespace prefixes

Tags: linq-to-xml

I have a number of files with an XML-like structure, but with undefined namespace prefixes. I only need to extract the data from these files, not to validate them. When trying to parse with `XElement.Load` or `XDocument.Load`, I get an `undefined prefix` exception. How can I do this (prefereably with LINQ to XML)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the prefixes ahead of time, add them yourself to a dummy root node and add the document to that dummy node.  Then you can parse and query your actual document.  However, you have to add this to the unparsed XML content *before* it is loaded/parsed.  Fortunately that can be relatively simple to accomplish.

e.g.,

```cs
XElement ParseFragment(string fragment, IDictionary<string, XNamespace> namespaces)
{
    var namespaceDefs = namespaces
        .Select(kvp => String.Format("xmlns:{0}=\"{1}\"", kvp.Key, kvp.Value.NamespaceName));
    var xml = String.Format(
        "<root {0}>{1}</root>",
        String.Join(" ", namespaceDefs),
        fragment);
    var root = XElement.Parse(xml);
    return root.Elements().Single();
}
```

```cs
XElement LoadFragment(TextReader fragmentReader, IDictionary<string, XNamespace> namespaces)
{
    var namespaceDefs = namespaces
        .Select(kvp => String.Format("xmlns:{0}=\"{1}\"", kvp.Key, kvp.Value.NamespaceName));
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine(String.Format("<root {0}>", String.Join(" ", namespaceDefs)));
    sb.AppendLine(fragmentReader.ReadToEnd());
    sb.AppendLine("</root>");
    var root = XElement.Load(new StringReader(sb.ToString()));
    return root.Elements().Single();
}
```

Then you can parse/load and query the element:

```cs
var fragment = @"<a:root><b:child>foo</b:child><b:child>bar</b:child></a:root>";
var namespaces = new Dictionary<string, XNamespace>
{
    { "a", "http://a.com" },
    { "b", "http://b.com" },
};
var element = ParseFragment(fragment, namespaces);
var b = namespaces["b"];
var childValues = element
    .Descendants(b + "child")
    .Select(child => (string)child);
```

Comment: And if I don't know the prefixes ahead of time, I'd have to repeatedly `try` parsing, and add a namespace based on the error message. I'll try this.